# Angular component use own module and pass data to child component in app module

Tags: angular, input, module, binding, angular8

I have parent component with it's own module and pass data to child component that imported in
app-module by using @input but there is error

*Can't bind to 'courseId' since it isn't a known property of 'app-rate-course'.

1. If 'app-rate-course' is an Angular component and it has 'courseId' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-rate-course' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.*

Comment: please share you code

Answer (score 0):

Import the child component in app.module.ts and add it to the declarations array

Answer (score 0):

Have you exported the component in module.ts file.

```
exports: [
    FeatureComponent
]
```